# Как добавить(или установить, не знаю как правильно) Apache Commons Math в Intel Idea?

Tags: java, apache

Как добавить(или установить, не знаю как правильно) Apache Commons Math в Intel Idea?

Answer (score 3):

`F4` по проекту. Вкладка `Libraries`. Жмешь плюсик -> From Maven.

Вводишь в поле поиска `commons-math3`. Ждешь поиска. Из списка выбираешь нужную версию. По желанию выбираешь куда загружать. Нажимаешь `ОК`. Все.

или.

Идешь [сюда](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi), качаешь архив из раздела `Binaries`. Создаешь папку в проекте. Помещаешь `commons-math3-*.*.*.jar` в эту папку. Далее. Заходишь в настройки проекта `F4`. Вкладка `Modules`. Таб `Dependicies`. Справа нажимаешь на плюсик. Выбираешь `JARs or directories`. Выбираешь папку которую ты создал. Нажимаешь Применить. Все.